# How can I make a single column dataframe using text files from different folders in the directory in python?

Tags: python-3.x

> Also how to extract only 30 .txt files from each folder?
>   Being a beginner it is very easy to read CSV files but I'm not able to succeed in this approach.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include what you have attempted so far in your question

Comment: Thank you @Andreas. I haven't attempted any code regarding this question because I don't know what is the approach for this method.For CSV import I used data = pd.read_csv(Path) but for above question I want to know the approach. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starter, you could create an empty `DataFrame` and setup the required columns and data type for the respective. Then, it would be better to set the name for the 30 `.txt` files to be sequential, so that you could loop through the text and load each of them. Do the same for the folder names, or create a list of paths and traverse through the list.

In addition to that, you might want to change the format to .csv instead, and use comma-separated values to specify the data.

For every text file, [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) the data to the `DataFrame` that you made in the beginning.

The pseudo-code for that would be something like this

```
# create DataFrame
# add column and set data type
# create list of folder paths
# for every folder:
#     for i in range(30):
#         read data from "text" + str(i) + ".csv"
#         append data to DataFrame
```

Comment: But sir I have seen an library called OS which has code : os.listdir(path='.') through this method can I import  .txt filies which limits to 30 .txt files. If code is possible please quote it sir. Thank you

Comment: Yes, that is another option. `listdir()` would return a list of entries in that directory, which you could loop through 30 times by setting a counter and breaking the loops when it reaches 30. Please consult the tutorials on how to implement that

Comment: Thank you @Andreas sir. My first experience is very good at StackOverflow. If possible please provide a link for best python tutorials with in depth python learning.

Comment: There is no such things that best tutorials, you could do a Google search on that and see which one suits you the best. If you are having a hard time, you might want to consider doing a more basic tasks at first.